# Not loading the texture with OBJ+MTL loader in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem. I wrote this function to load an obj and mtl model
(taken from:https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl):

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

//mtlLoader.setTexturePath(path)
mtlLoader.setPath(path);

mtlLoader.load(material, function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath(path);

    objLoader.load(model, function ( mesh ) {

        mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
        mesh.scale.set(s, s, s);
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
        mesh.castShadow = false;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add(mesh);

        if(handler) {

            handler(mesh);
        }

    }, function(e){}, function(e){} );
});
```

Where material is file.mtl and model is file.obj. It works fine for this model: https://free3d.com/3d-model/hk416-with-animation-37927.html but it doesn't work for another obj+mtl. The texture is not loaded and I see only white model. Why?

I use three.js r85.

Thank you!!

Comment: can you point to an OBJ and an MTL file that doesn't work, too?

Comment: Yes!! You are right!! i.e. https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/exterior/sci-fi/hand-painted-fountain

Comment: That model has an OBJ file and the textures, but no MTL file.

Comment: oh.. right. But in this model https://free3d.com/3d-model/tree-74556.html i have all I need (mtl, obj) but i see only white model..

Comment: check for errors in the console. Also check under the network tab in console to see what is actually loading

Comment: i haven't error in the console and in the network tab I see it loads the tree.mtl and the tree.obj but I see only black model (or white in another case)..

Comment: I try to use blender and I see that the texture is not load..is possible that the file .mtl is incomplete?